# Change RGB content of picture with .split to bands

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am trying to apply a "filter" to a picture to change to Red and Green and Blue content to 0.1, 0.5 and 0.9 the original content. I am using python and pillow as demanded for this course work

Right now i am trying to split the color parts into different pictures by applying the .split method. 
Next up i would like to multiply the different parts of the original pictures with 0,1 and 0.5 and 0.9 
For that i conerted it to a matrix with numpy.array()
Is this the way to go? And if so, how do i convert the changed matrix back to a picture?

```
import PIL
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter
from PIL import ImageEnhance
import numpy

from IPython.display import display
# read image and convert to RGB
image=Image.open("readonly/msi_recruitment.gif")
image=image.convert('RGB')
image_bands = image.split()
rot = image_bands[0]
grün = image_bands[1]
blau = image_bands[2]
#display(image_bands)
print(x)
z = numpy.array(rot)
z = z * [0.1]

display(z)
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the type of `image` not a numpy array? If it is, you could do this in one shot because of broadcasting. So assuming the shape of `image` is `(n, m, 3)`, `image*np.array([0.1, 0.5, 0.9]).reshape((1, 1, 3))`

Comment: The multiplikation with image*numpy.array ... works fine. But what i get as a result is again a matrix with i do not know how to plot as an image.
Do you have an idea on how i could do that?

Comment: Try [`imshow`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) from matplotlib. In jupyter, don't forget the `%matplotlib inline` magic.

Comment: but also, did `display` not work? In your code you are passing a numpy array to `display` already...

Comment: see [`Image.fromarray()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.fromarray)

Comment: i will try imshow tomorrow, since i have to work now, but until now when i use display on a matrix it would just display the matrix and not the picture 
the Image.fromarray() seems to work! thank you

Comment: i have not the perfect picture yet but at least now i have a picture from an array!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be tempted to just do most of it in numpy.  start by loading libraries and opening image:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open('filename.png').convert('RGB')
```

then convert straight to a numpy array:

```
arr = np.array(im, dtype=float)
```

note that this will give you an array of shape `(height, width, 3)` where the 3 final elements are the RGB channels, i.e. `arr[:,:,0]` is the red channel.  the reason for the `dtype=float` is to make your "filter" easier as you can't directly do your `red * 0.1` with integer datatypes (images are mostly `uint8`).

you can then do your transform:

```
arr[:,:,0] *= 0.1
arr[:,:,1] *= 0.5
arr[:,:,2] *= 0.9
```

and convert back to a PIL/Pillow Image, making sure to get back to the right datatype on the way:

```
Image.fromarray(arr.astype(np.uint8))
```

which Jupyter displays inline nicely for me

note that if you wanted to use less memory, you could use something like:

```
arr = np.array(im)
arr[:,:,0] //= 10
arr[:,:,1] //= 2
arr[:,:,2] -= arr[:,:,2] // 10
Image.fromarray(arr)
```

but it's awkward to do things like this as your "filters" get more complicated

Comment: Wow, that totally works! Thank you very much. This basically solves my question.