# How to change the intensity of each "band"(color) of the RGB in an image?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, rgb

After loading an image in RGB mode and using the `open()` function from the PIL library, I'd like to adjust the intensity of each color (Red, Green and Blue) in the image and to have 3 image variations of `0.1`, `0.5` and `0.9` intensity of each color. After some research, I've found a few people refer to it as "channel" or "band". I thought this could be achieved by using the `PIL.ImageEnhance.Color` class from the ImageEnhance Module, yet it didn't work out. Any suggestions how to change each "channel" intensity?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("bride.jpg")
```

Comment: what means "didn't work out." ? Do you get error ? What did you tried ? Show it in questiona. And always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Like this... https://stackoverflow.com/a/56323081/2836621

Comment: this seems like a standard tutorial question as it keeps popping up.  I answered a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57041125/1358308 but @MarkSetchell's solution is much nicer

Comment: Here is another easy way - it just depends how your mind works as to which you will get on with better... https://stackoverflow.com/a/54363962/2836621